# kubectl exec with curl Connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, curl, kubectl, apache-pulsar

i cannot execute successfully a curl command inside a running pod

```
$ kubectl exec -t pulsar-pulsar-manager-79c6769595-xd596 -- bash -c "CSRF_TOKEN=$(curl -v  http://localhost:7750/pulsar-manager/csrf-token)"
```

connect to ::1 port 7750 failed: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1:7750...
connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7750 failed: Connection refused
Failed to connect to localhost port 7750: Connection refused
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 7750: Connection refused

But when i login to the container and execute the command, there is no issue

```
$ kubectl exec -ti pulsar-pulsar-manager-79c6769595-xd596  -- bash
$ CSRF_TOKEN=$(curl  http://localhost:7750/pulsar-manager/csrf-token)
```

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    36  100    36    0     0   2400      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2400

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the token and stores it the host shell:

> CSRF_TOKEN=$(kubectl exec -t pulsar-pulsar-manager-79c6769595-xd596 -- bash -c "curl -s http://localhost:7750/pulsar-manager/csrf-token")

If you want to get the token in the container:

> kubectl exec -t pulsar-pulsar-manager-79c6769595-xd596 -- bash -c "CSRF_TOKEN=\$(curl -v  http://localhost:7750/pulsar-manager/csrf-token)"

Comment: i need the token to be in the container, i want to execute another curl command with it

Comment: updated the answer, you have to escape the dollar in the cmd